# creating aggredated pivot tables in R for multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have 2 dataset

```
data1=structure(list(x1 = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), x2 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), x3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), x4 = c(156L, 156L, 238L, 156L, 238L, 238L, 156L, 
156L, 156L), x5 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x5.1 = c(31L, 
1L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 2L), x6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("En", "RU"), class = "factor"), 
    x7 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("13", 
    "other"), class = "factor"), x8 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), x9 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L), 
    x10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x11 = c(745L, 
    120L, 140L, 200L, 130L, 410L, 460L, 460L, 675L), x12 = c(440L, 
    120L, 140L, 200L, 130L, 410L, 460L, 460L, 445L), x13 = c(2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L), prediction = structure(c(1L, 
    5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("0.0646", "0.0713", 
    "0.1319", "0.2629", "0.3479", "0.3693", "0.4037", "0.4123"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

and second dataset

```
data2=structure(list(pred = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0226902365684509", "0.0326902365684509", 
"0.0826902365684509", "0.1211001253128052", "0.411001253128052", 
"0.611001253128052", "0.64564001253128052"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

How for each variable `x1-x13` create pivot table with `data1$prediction` and `data2$pred`
aggerated by means

For example desired output for variable x1

```
x1  mean_prediction mean_pred
7   0.31            0.056
6   0.14            0.569
```

I.E in output must 12 tables in one dataframe. and not separated data frames.
How to do it?

#update

```
structure(list(x1 = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), x2 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), x3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), x4 = c(156L, 156L, 238L, 156L, 238L, 238L, 156L, 
156L, 156L), x5 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x5.1 = c(31L, 
1L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 2L), x6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("En", "RU"), class = "factor"), 
    x7 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("13", 
    "other"), class = "factor"), x8 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), x9 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L), 
    x10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x11 = c(745L, 
    120L, 140L, 200L, 130L, 410L, 460L, 460L, 675L), x12 = c(440L, 
    120L, 140L, 200L, 130L, 410L, 460L, 460L, 445L), x13 = c(2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L), prediction = structure(c(1L, 
    5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("0.0646", "0.0713", 
    "0.1319", "0.2629", "0.3479", "0.3693", "0.4037", "0.4123"
    ), class = "factor"), pred = c(0.121100125, 0.032690237, 
    0.022690237, 0.082690237, 0.022690237, 0.411001253, 0.645640013, 
    0.611001253, 0.611001253)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: How is `data1$prediction` and `data2$pred` related?

Comment: @RonakShah, these datasrts can be bind by cbind. It is ok. i just copy  pred and paste in new dataset

Comment: `data1` has 9 rows and `data2` has 10. I don't think we can directly `cbind`.

Comment: @RonakShah, it is my bug,please, check edited post, i did cbind , here must be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your dput. First convert the factors into characters for ease of dealing with.

```
data1$x6<-as.character(data1$x6)
data1$x7<-as.character(data1$x7)
```

Then, convert the value columns to numeric from character factors as they are in your code.

```
data1$prediction<-as.numeric(as.character.numeric_version(data1$prediction))
data2$pred<-as.numeric(as.character.numeric_version(data2$pred))
```

Due to the additional column in the data2 code, remove the last row of the data to use.

```
data1$pred<-data2$pred[1:nrow(data1)]
```

Here, is a function, which take the string name of the column then, creates a tibble with the needed data for the output, converts the grouping columns value to characters (as some of the columns contain numbers and some contain strings, this eliminates the error of not getting all the grouping values), then outputs the grouped means for the values in the column.

```
get_column_break_down<-function(colname, df=data1) {
  res_df<-tibble(group = as.character(df[,grep(paste0('^',colname,'$'), names(df))]),
  prediction=df$prediction,
  pred=df$pred)
  return(res_df %>%
       group_by(group) %>%
       summarize(mean_prediction = mean(prediction),
                 mean_pred = mean(pred)) %>%
       mutate(predictor = colname) %>%
       ungroup() %>%
       select(predictor, group, mean_prediction, mean_pred))
}
```

Get a vector of the columns names from `data1`

```
colname_vec<-names(data1[,1:14])
```

Create the initial `data.frame` or in this case `tibble` with the first column name.

```
df<-get_column_break_down(colname_vec[1])
```

Loop through the remaining columns, binding the rows to the `df` variable, or stacking the rows on top of each other.

```
for(n in colname_vec[2:length(colname_vec)]) {
    df<-bind_rows(df, get_column_break_down(n))
}
```

Finally here is the output.

***Note, as it is a tibble, it is rounding the numbers, if you inspect the `df` variable in your enviroment or write it to a csv, the numbers will closely match you numbers.***

```
df
# A tibble: 49 x 4
 predictor group mean_prediction mean_pred
 <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 x1        6               0.150    0.570 
 2 x1        7               0.320    0.0564
 3 x2        1               0.197    0.611 
 4 x2        2               0.257    0.191 
 5 x3        1               0.242    0.243 
 6 x3        2               0.249    0.368 
 7 x4        156             0.225    0.351 
 8 x4        238             0.281    0.152 
 9 x5        0               0.205    0.349 
10 x5        1               0.380    0.0577
# ... with 39 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data in long format , group for each column name and value and take `mean` for  `prediction` and `pred` columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(x1:x13, as.character), 
         prediction = as.numeric(as.character(prediction))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = x1:x13) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(across(c(prediction, pred), mean, na.rm = TRUE))

#   name  value prediction   pred
#   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 x1    6         0.150  0.570 
# 2 x1    7         0.320  0.0564
# 3 x10   0         0.257  0.186 
# 4 x10   1         0.197  0.628 
# 5 x11   120       0.348  0.0327
# 6 x11   130       0.404  0.0227
# 7 x11   140       0.369  0.0227
# 8 x11   200       0.412  0.0827
# 9 x11   410       0.0713 0.411 
#10 x11   460       0.132  0.628 
# … with 39 more rows
```